# compare the numbers: $A = \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$ and $B =\frac{b}{a} + \frac{a}{c }+\frac{c}{b}$

Tags: number-comparison

**question**

Let's compare the numbers:
$A = \frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}$ and $B =\frac{b}{a} + \frac{a}{c }+\frac{c}{b}$,
where $a, b, c$ are real numbers such that: $0<a<b<c$

**idea**

because $a<b$, $\frac{a}{b}<1<\frac{b}{a}$

because $b<c$, $\frac{b}{c}<1<\frac{c}{b}$

because $a<c$, $\frac{a}{c}<1<\frac{c}{a}$

I don't know what to do next. I tried using AM-GM but with no result.
Hope one of you can help me!

Comment: The duplicate target can be found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Ba%7D%20%3E%20%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Ba%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bc%20%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Bb%7D%20%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I did not see that an answer has already been posted a few minutes before mine (I was typing out this answer when it was posted)  that uses a similiar method as mine, but as beginner myself, I feel the need to explain steps more thoroughly and the thinking behind employing this method, so I am posting the following answer :

I think the approach in such questions (where we can see removing the fraction appears to simplify the question) is to first convert both sides to non - fractional terms. So as a,b,c > $0$ we can multiply A and B by abc (to remove fractional terms) and if A > B then abcA > abcB. So let $abcA = x = a^2c + b^2a  + c^2b \;\&\; abcB = y = b^2c + a^2b + c^2a$.

Assume x > y (another thought process in such questions where we can't directly apply any inequalities of theorems) and subtracting x on both sides we get $y - x < 0$

Substituting x and y and clubbing square terms together we get :

$a^2(b-c) + b^2(c-a) + c^2(a-b) < 0$

Let us write c - a as (c - b) + (b - a)

So we get $a^2(b-c) + b^2((c-b)+(b-a)) + c^2(a-b) < 0 \equiv -a^2(c-b) + b^2(c-b) + b^2(b-a) - c^2(b-a) < 0$

Clubbing respective terms together we get :

$(b^2-a^2)(c-b) + (b^2-c^2)(b-a) < 0$

Using $n^2 - m^2 = (n-m)(n+m)$ we get :

$(b-a)(b+a)(c-b) + (b-c)(b+c)(b-a) < 0 \equiv (b-a)(b+a)(c-b) - (c-b)(c+b)(b-a) < 0$

Since c > b > a, (b-a) and (c-b) are positive so we can divide by (b-a)(c-b) on both sides to get :

$(b+a) - (c+b) < 0 \equiv a-c < 0$ which is true (as a < c is given)

Thus our intial assumption was true that $x > y \implies A > B$

Answer (score 4):

$A-B=\dfrac{(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)}{abc}>0$, hence $A>B$.